# Removing double tags from XML document

Tags: xml, transformation

I'm trying to transform a document where I have things like

```
<tag1>
   <tag1>
      <tag2>....</tag2>
      <tag3>....</tag3>
      <tag4>
         <tag4>
           <tag5>...</tag5>
           .
           .
         </tag4>
    </tag1>
</tag1>
```

I'd like to remove the duplicate tag1 and tag4. I won't know the names of the tags before I open the xml file.

---

**Update**

Right. I have

```
<xsl:template match="body/body"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Which was a test for removing...

```
<body> 
    <body> 
        ---more xml here-- 
    </body> 
</body>
```

And that worked just fine removing one of the body tags. What I need is a more generic match expression to allow me to catch and remove any double tags, because I won't know until run-time what the double tags will be.

What should I write in my xsl stylesheet?

Comment: So you need to include an example of your xsl stylesheet, showing what you have attempted. Where anything has not produced the expected result. You should not ask a "Do it for me" question.

Comment: Right.

I have
    <xsl:template match="body/body">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

Which was a test for removing 
    ...
    <body>
      <body>
         ---more xml here--
      </body>
    </body>

And that worked just fine removing one of the body tags. What I need is a more generic match expression to allow me to catch and remove any double tags, because I won't know until runtime what the double tags will be

Comment: A link to a good page where I can read about what I can do in the "match" expression will also be welcomed. I'm not that well-versed in xml transforms

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I'll post it here in case others have the same problem:

```
<xsl:template match="*[name()=name(..)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It compares the name of the tag with the name of the parent tag ( name(..) ).